# Incorrect order of graph plotting using Flot chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flot

I have a simple angular directive that uses the flot chart library. The issue i am facing is that my graph seems to be plotting in an incorrect manner.

```
if(value == 'year'){
                scope.tempHumChartOptions.xaxis = {
                mode: "time",
                tickSize: [1, "month"],
            monthNames: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],

}
```

From the code above - i'm simply trying to plot my X-Axis starting from Jan until December, but for some reason it begins from February and goes on until January. 
[image]

Also as you can see - I am facing some sort of issue with the alignment.

Is there anything i am missing out on here?

Comment: What are the min/max options for the axis? What is the data? What are the timezones for data and browser (are they the same)?

Comment: The monthNames you see is the x-axis data, but it's skipping the first Jan 2016 like I mentioned. The y-axis is an array of values between 0-100 (or more), I set that dynamically. The main issue is that of this x-axis, not sure why it starts from Feb? The dates are converted from UTC to ET.

Comment: "The dates are converted from UTC to ET." - That is probably your problem. The tick label for Jan 2016 would show at 2016-01-01 00:00 UTC, but your data starts at 2016-01-01 05:00 UTC (= 00:00 ET).